# create new object task for the current logged in user

Tags: python, django

hi i want to create a new task for the current logged in user so i am using this views 
this is my views

```
@login_required
def ajouter_task(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.save(commit=False)
            task.user = request.user
            task.save()
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = TaskForm()
    return render_to_response('ajouter_task.html', {'form': form})
```

it dosn't work i don't know where the problem is , please help and thank u in advance

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What exactly is the problem /  error?

Comment: You haven't worded your question well, as mentioned above. I'd also recommend fixing the missing code path where your form is not valid.

Comment: thank u for answering  when i click on add it gives me this error : Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: in your template, you're probably not including {% csrf_token %} when you render your form. You'd need to adjust your question to provide more code (your template and your form code) before getting further help

Comment: You should use `render(request, ...)` instead of `render_to_response`.

Answer (score 0):

this is my template i already included {% csrf_token %}

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'ajouter_task' %}">{% csrf_token %}

                    <span class="login100-form-title">
                        ajouter votre Taches :
                    </span>

                        <div class="form-group clearfix">
                            <label for="{{ form.titre.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 control-label text-right">Titre<span class="text-red"></span>:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                                {{ form.titre }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group clearfix">
                            <label for="{{ form.date.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 control-label text-right">Date:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6"><input type="date" class="form-control"/>
                                {{ form.date }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group clearfix">
                            <label for="{{ form.objectif.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 control-label text-right">Objectif:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                                {{ form.objectif }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group clearfix">
                            <label for="{{ form.theme.id_for_label }}" class="col-md-4 control-label text-right">Theme:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                                {{ form.theme }}
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn" href="{% url 'home' %}">
                            ajouter
                        </button>
                    </div>



                </form>
```

my urls.py is

```
url(r'^ajouter_task/$', views.ajouter_task, name='ajouter_task'),
```